# How to hide inspections widget in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, widget, hide, inspection

Since IntelliJ 2020.2, there is an overlay on the editor that is distracting.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#change-highlighting-level-for-file

Is there a way to hide this "widget"?

Comment: You may switch to "Compact View" under three dots.